# $.post jQuery send post data

Tags: jquery, post

I have seen so many questions and answers about this here, but I can't get it work.  What am I doing wrong ?

```
function addVote(trainingID , guiderID , StudentID){    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../server/addVote.php",
        data: { "trainingsID":  trainingID , "StudentID":  StudentID  ,"GuiderID":  guiderID  }
    }); 
}
```

I also tried to send it as a string, but it is still not working.

If I run it like this it works, but I want to use the previous version.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../server/addVote.php?trainingsID="+trainingID+"&StudentID="+StudentID+"&GuiderID="+guiderID
});
```

Comment: you have an extra `,` after your `data` line. And have you done ANY basic debugging, like checking your browser's debug console?

Comment: thanks, but no change

Comment: @MarcB The extra comma is allowed, except on very old browsers.

Comment: The code here looks fine. Maybe the problem is in the server code, which you haven't posted.

Comment: can you provide some error code or log?

Comment: Shouldn't => data: { trainingsID:  trainingID  be => data: {" trainingsID":  trainingID ,

Comment: tried that no result, I get seccess no error , but it seems that the data hadn't passed

Comment: If you put the parameters in the URL, they'll be in `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.'

Comment: @AmitSingh You don't need to quote property names unless they contain special characters or they're reserved words.

Comment: @Akshay POST parameters aren't JSON.

Comment: @Barmar thanks that was the problem . I used _GET on the server side instead of post

Comment: Why are you using `type: "POST"` if you want to use URL parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the parameters in the URL, they're put in `$_GET` on the server, not `$_POST`. So use `$_GET['trainingsID']`, and so on.

If you want to be able to use the script with either `GET` or `POST` parameters, you can use `$_REQUEST` in PHP -- it contains both sets of parameters combined.